# SSIS Expression Builder - How to find last occurrence of a character

Tags: ssis, ssis-2016

I have values that look like this:

```
D:\DM-250\Insert_Jobs-QA-UAT\14-FILE_A_UpdateInsert.dts

D:\DM-250\Insert_Jobs-QA-UAT\Something_DaisyChain\14-stuff_and_things_UpdateInsert.dts

D:\DM-250\14-another_file.dts
```

I want the very ends of these 3 values, starting from the last `"\"` character.

I tried to use `FINDSTRING`, but I don't know how to grab the last occurrence of a character.

Any suggestions?

Comment: try using reverse

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This will give you the position from the right.

```
findstring(reverse([your column]),"\",1)
```

I am guessing you are trying to extract filename which is:

```
right([your column], [result from above] - 1)
```

Comment: I came up with a solution using Token and token count, but let me see if yours is easier.