# How do I write an SSIS Expression to extract one folder name from a fully qualified file name

Tags: sql, visual-studio, ssis, sql-server-data-tools

I have an SSIS package with an ForEach File Enumerate loop (Fully Qualified Name) with an FTP task within in.

The package when executed will go through the files in the **subfolders** within the following directory

C:\Test\Test2\ABC\

*.txt

And it will post the files to an FTP site.

I have a defined variable called @[User::Filename] within the foreach loop.

But there are folders within the FTP and I want the files to go to based on the Folder they are taken from on the C drive.

C:\Test\Test2\ABC\A\1.txt

C:\Test\Test2\ABC\B\2.txt

C:\Test\Test2\ABC\C\3.txt

File 1.txt should go to the FTP folder Called \FTP\A

File 2.txt should go to the FTP folder Called \FTP\B

File 3.txt should go to the FTP folder Called \FTP\C

My original thought was to make the remote path a variable and piggy back off the the foreach loop variable Fully qualified name.

To do this I created a variable called @[User::FilenameFTP] and inputted the following into the expression

```
"//FTP//" + 

 RIGHT(
       (LEFT(@[User::Filename], ABS((FINDSTRING(@[User::Filename], "//", 5)))), 

       ABS((FINDSTRING(@[User::Filename], "//", 5)-1)) - ABS((FINDSTRING(@[User::Filename], "//",4)+1))
      )
```

I thought this formula would give me the filename in the C drive which the file is coming from and I used this as the Remote Path variable within the FTP task.  But when I run it the files still go into \FTP\ and not into the subfolders.

I ran a script task on this and the output isnt showing what I want either.  What am I doing wrong?  Can this not be done this way editing the variable within the foreach loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your drive names are coming in (more or less) as you have them shown, then those should be backslashes (`"\\"`) instead of forward slashes in your expression. Might not be the issue, but I changed them to play around with this.

Using the `C` folder string, in the expression as written, `ABS((FINDSTRING(@[User::Filename], "\\", 5)-1))` and `ABS((FINDSTRING(@[User::Filename], "\\",4)+1))` both evaluate to 19, so the expression comes down to `RIGHT(<<String>>,0)`, and, from the documentation, [If integer_expression is zero, the function returns a zero-length string.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/right-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks). So you're not appending anything to the end of the FTP base folder name.

## Down and Dirty Fix

We could probably mess around with all that `LEFT` and `RIGHT` and `FINDSTRING`, but if you know that the folder name you're after will always be the fifth element in your fully qualified name (which your expression is already dependent on) you can get there faster just using [`TOKEN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/expressions/token-ssis-expression?view=sql-server-ver15), and specifying the fifth element of your slash-delimited string:

```
"//FTP//" + TOKEN( @[User::Filename],"\\",5) +"//"
```

Which evaluates to `//FTP//C//`.

## More Sustainable Fix

On the other hand, if you want to future-proof your code a little, in anticipation of the day that you add or eliminate a level of folder hierarchy, I would suggest extracting the last folder name, without regard to how many levels of folder come first.

We can do that using `SUBSTRING` and some clever `REVERSE` work, with due credit to [KeithL](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3325290/) for [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52821910/5790584), that got me rolling.

`SUBSTRING` takes three arguments. We have our string `@[User::Filename]`, so that's one. The second is the starting position from the left end of the string, and the third is the number of characters to extract.

To get the starting position, we'll find the position of the second to last slash using `REVERSE` to count characters from the right hand end of the string:

```
FINDSTRING(REVERSE( @[User::Filename]),"\\",2) (evaluates to 8 here)
```

So our starting position is the total length of the string, minus the number of characters back to the second to last slash.

```
LEN( @[User::Filename]) - FINDSTRING(REVERSE( @[User::Filename]),"\\",2) (=17)
```

We can get the number of characters to pull by subtracting the reversed position of the last slash from the reversed position of the second to last slash, then subtracting one more, since we don't want that trailing slash in our string yet.

```
FINDSTRING(REVERSE( @[User::Filename]),"\\",2) 
- FINDSTRING(REVERSE( @[User::Filename]),"\\",1) - 1 (= 1 in our example)
```

And there are our three arguments. Putting those all together with your base folder name (and I added a trailing slash. If that doesn't work for you, take it out of there!):

```
"//FTP//" 
+ SUBSTRING( 
      @[User::Filename] ,
      LEN( @[User::Filename]) - FINDSTRING(REVERSE( @[User::Filename]),"\\",2),
      FINDSTRING(REVERSE( @[User::Filename]),"\\",2)
        -FINDSTRING(REVERSE( @[User::Filename]),"\\",1)-1 )
+ "//"
```

Evaluates to `//FTP//C//`.

Now, when the powers that be decide to "clean up" that source server, and the `Test2` layer disappears all of a sudden, or things get crazy, and you bury this all one layer deeper, your code will still work.

## Side Note

If you're really using drive letters in your file path names, like `C:\`, be aware that when you're running your packages locally, that's your C:\ drive the package is using, but when you deploy this, it'll be looking around on the *server's* C:\ drive, and it just might not like what it finds, or more likely, doesn't find there.

Comment: Eric thank you so so much! I used the Token command you mentioned and it worked exactly as I intended.  I will review your long term solution as well as you mention it may be worth it when deploying into a production environment.    Thank you again I was struggling on this one.

Comment: @JustinStaugaitis, SSIS expressions are almost always a struggle! Just enough different from standar SQL to drive you crazy. Glad it helped!